# printing "form 1" into the combo box everytime it is used c#

Tags: c#

Every time I use the combo box to add a record, it then adds "form 1" to the bottom of the combo box list, I can't seem to find why, other than something to do with iCount?

I'm a beginner, please help

```
//initialise array of module codes
string[] sMonths = new string[] { "01", "02", "03", "04", "05",
                               "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" };

//initialise combo box from sModules array
for (int iCount = 0; iCount < sMonths.Length; iCount++)
{
    cboMonth.Items.Add(sMonths[iCount]);

}
```

After looking further, i think the error is happening somewhere here....

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("EVENTS.TXT", true))
        {

            sw.WriteLine(txtEvent.Text);

            sw.WriteLine(txtVenue.Text);

            sw.WriteLine(cboMonth.Items.Add(Text));

            sw.WriteLine(lstActivity.SelectedItem);



            if (rdoRange1.Checked == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(rdoRange1.Text);
            }
            else if (rdoRange2.Checked == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(rdoRange2.Text);
            }
            else if (rdoRange3.Checked == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(rdoRange3.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine(rdoRange4.Text);
            }

            sw.Close();
        }
```

Comment: don't think it's something in that code. You need to show more code where the combo is used.

Comment: Edit->Find and replace->find in files: search for "Add("form 1")" in the entire solution. Some where it is getting added accidentally.

Comment: If it appears under those elements, then it is most probably added before them. I have strange feeling that the combobox is actually initialized with a field 'form 1 '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line :

```
sw.WriteLine(cboMonth.Items.Add(Text));
```

It adds an additional item to your combobox, most probably that's 'form 1'